# Sabre HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ error ERR.SWS.PROVIDER.REQUEST_HANDLER_ERROR

Tags: soap, sabre

I am getting error Unexpected request processing error when trying to get rates in sabre soap api. Here is my request xml:

```
<soapenv:Body>
              <ns:HotelRateDescriptionRQ ReturnHostCommand="false" Version="2.3.0">
                 <ns:AvailRequestSegment>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ns:GuestCounts Count="2"/>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ns:HotelSearchCriteria>
                       <ns:Criterion>
                          <ns:HotelRef HotelCode="46333"/>
                       </ns:Criterion>
                    </ns:HotelSearchCriteria>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ns:RatePlanCandidates>
                       <ns:RatePlanCandidate CurrencyCode="USD"/>
                    </ns:RatePlanCandidates>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <ns:TimeSpan End="12-28" Start="12-25"/>
                 </ns:AvailRequestSegment>
              </ns:HotelRateDescriptionRQ>    
    </soapenv:Body>
```

But i got error response:

```
    <soap-env:Body>
        <HotelRateDescriptionRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" Version="2.3.0">
            <stl:ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
                <stl:Error type="Application" timeStamp="2018-02-15T01:50:26-06:00">
                    <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                        <stl:Message>Unexpected request processing error</stl:Message>
                        <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.PROVIDER.REQUEST_HANDLER_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
                    </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
        </HotelRateDescriptionRS>
    </soap-env:Body>
```

so what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this problem, the problem because i use token from service TokenCreateRQ, it should use service SessionCreateRS

Answer (score -1):

Possible Solutions:

1) have you set the ns: arrcordingly ?
`xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10"

xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`

2) Did you set the service type in the header accordingly?
`<eb:Service eb:type="OTA">HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Service>`
`<eb:Action>HotelPropertyDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Action>`

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: yes i have set header cirrectly.
`<eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
         <eb:Service eb:type="OTA"></eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ</eb:Action>
        /eb:MessageHeader>`

Comment: and body i have changed, same with sabre documentation http://webservices.sabre.com/drc/servicedoc/HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ_v2.3.0_Design.xml

Comment: You should probably not start using the endpoint you are using. According to the https://developer.sabre.com/resources/api_versioning it gets switched to https://api.havail.sabre.com by mid of the year. Can you provide the full request (including exact adress and header (w/o token obviously))

Comment: i have fixed this problem, the problem because i use token from service TokenCreateRQ, it should use service SessionCreateRS